# How to get specific array element?

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have the following array of strings:

```
$data_array = array("the dog is hairy", "cats like treats", "my mouse is tired");
```

I want to write a function that will extract an element from the array based on whether it contains another string.

For example, if the array element contains the string "dog" i want to return the string "the dog is hairy" for use elsewhere.

I tried using a foreach loop but it didn't work:

```
foreach ($data_array as $sentence){
    if (stripos($sentence, "dog")){
        echo $sentence;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: It looks like it's working? http://codepad.org/BpYE0lHf

Comment: And as @AurelioDeRosa points out, you're best checking for a non-false value since `0` could be interpreted as a falsy value.

Comment: yep that's what was happening, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use stripos this is the code:

```
   $data_array = array("the dog is hairy", "cats like treats", "my mouse is tired");
   foreach($data_array as $value)
   {
      if (stripos($value, 'dog') !== FALSE)
         echo $value;
   }
```

Comment: no need to use foreach or any loop  process to do it. Check my example.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me.

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/064bf

```
<?php 
$data_array = array("the dog is hairy", "cats like treats", "my mouse is tired"); 
foreach($data_array as $data){ 
    if (false !== stripos($data, "dog")){ 
        echo $data; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The third sentence (about using an appropriate variable for `stripos()`). The OP doesn't seem to suggest this was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($data_array as $val) {
  if (strstr($val, 'dog')) {
    echo $val;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I just edited my question. I tried that and it didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example:

```
$f_array = preg_grep('/dog/i', $data_array);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use [`preg_grep()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
$found_array = preg_grep( '/dog/i', $data_array );
```

Edit: Added `/i` switch for case-insensitive matching.

Comment: This solution slow the performance. RegEx are always slower than string comparison.

Comment: Regex compilation does carry an overhead, but so does `foreach`.  I haven't done a benchmark, but I wouldn't be surprised if this wasn't faster than the `foreach`-based solutions.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: I did run a quick benchmark, and it seems that using `preg_grep()` is from twice (for the three-element input array given by the OP) to four times (for a 98000 word dictionary) faster than using `foreach` and `stripos()` as in your answer.

Comment: You answered yourself. Test regex in a real contest. Use an array of thousand element where every value have a long lenght and then the test will says something correct. Anyway you can ask to everyone you want and everybody will tell you that the regex have to be used mildly.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: OK, since you insist: 1000 lines (of which 220 match), 302262 bytes total (avg. 302.262 bytes/line), repeated 10000 times: `preg_grep()` 15.940 seconds; `stripos()` 31.509 seconds.  If you don't find these benchmarks convincing, why not try running your own?

Comment: You just stole my answer. Good try.